# Collision dont work

Tags: collision

The line goes through the hook instead of bypassing it. The line is made with a soft body. I added a collision to the hook. And in the soft body settings, I checked the self collision, but it still doesn't work in this case. When I make a straight line and plane underneath it it normally works, in the case of a lap it doesn't work

The rope itself is made of single vert and skin

Please,maybe someone know why ?

[image]